# Blue cursor icon next to file in Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer - what does it mean?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, icons, visual-studio-2017

What does this blue cursor icon next to a file mean? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with TFS:

[image]

Also note that I just moved all these images into a subfolder, which may be related to the meaning of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blue cursor icon means you have changed the `file name` or `file location` within the source control.

In you case, you moved these images into a subfolder. So, the file location changed.

[image]

Comment: Great - thanks! I wish this were documented somewhere.